# RichFaces 4 replacement for <a4j:loadScript>

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm currently migrating a legacy JSF 1.2 application using RichFaces 3.3 to JSF 2.0 and RichFaces 4.

However, inclusion of the jQuery library bundled with RichFaces does no longer work by including `<a4j:loadScript src="resource://jquery.js"/>`, as the `<a4j:loadScript>` component has been removed from RichFaces version 4.

The [RF 3.3 to 4 migration guide](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration) does not state how to include the bundled scripts otherwise.
I've seen suggestions to use `<h:outputScript name="jquery.js" target="head" />`, but this produces no output whatever in the rendered page.

Has anyone got a solution to load those bundled scripts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `<h:outputScript target="head">` to work, you need to have a `<h:head>` instead of a `<head>` in the master template.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, RichFaces 4 already ships with bundled jQuery. You do not necessarily need to load one yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, you pushed me in the right direction. The underlying problem was caused by PrettyFaces messing with the resource URLs for some reason, though. :)