# JSF richfaces causes javascript to stop working

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I use javascript for my dropdown menu, is works perfectly on all pages except the pages that use richfaces. Im using the latest version of richfaces 4.3.4. here is where i import my js.

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="excanvas.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-ui.custom.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.flot.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.flot.resize.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.sparkline.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="fullcalendar.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.jpanelmenu.min.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="unicorn.js" />
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="unicorn.dashboard.js" />
```

Is there any conflict between them? why is it that it works but only on pages without richfaces?  regards

Comment: See: http://jee-bpel-soa.blogspot.in/2009/04/tips-and-tricks-on-jquery-and-richfaces.html

Comment: Still not sure what to do? the link is outdated and a4j:loadScript does not exist anymore

Comment: Richfaces uses jquery too, so you are likely using two differente versions of jquery. That could cause some problems.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution to my problem thanks,

replaced:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.min.js" />
```

with:

```
<h:outputScript name="jquery.js" />
```

thanks to Pablo for the mention and the answer from BalusC in this thread: 
[How to enforce loading of jQuery in RichFaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587769/how-to-enforce-the-loading-of-jquery-in-richfaces)